# Js next previous button from array

Tags: javascript

i have difficulties for displaying value my 'period' variable, i have this form who can be fill in actual by period. this is my form:

[FORM VIEW SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTjW2.png)

I just want to activated the button arrow to change value of Week period in array, be the best if how to show today week as a default. :D

This is my sample code:

#### FORM.PHP

```
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"  style="text-align:right;">
    <a id="previous" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round"><i class=en-arrow-left8></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1" style="text-align:center;">
    <input id="act4" class=form-control name="act">
    <span class="help-block text-center" id="demo"></span>
    <hr>
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-alt btn-primary">SAVE</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">
    <input id="tgt4" class=form-control value="" disabled>
    <span class="help-block text-center"><?PHP echo $tdy; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">
    <a id="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-round"><i class=en-arrow-right8></i></a>
  </div>
```

#### Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var messages = [ { "Week-01" }, { "Week-02" }, { "Week-03" } ];

  var messageIndex = 0;

  $("#previous").on("click", function(){
    messageIndex = (messageIndex + messages.length -1) % (messages.length);    
    $("demo").text(messages[messageIndex].content);});

  $("#next").on("click", function(){
    messageIndex = (messageIndex+1) % (messages.length);    
    $("demo").text(messages[messageIndex].content);});

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = messageIndex;
</script>
```

Comment: The problem I see is that you use `messages[messageIndex].content` to get a value, but `content` property is not set in `messages`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I've not tested it.

You'd also need the # ref on the jQuery selector.
Change the array to just be a simple array rather than an object array.
Just increment decrement the index and ensure that it can't go too high or low.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var messages = [ "Week-01", "Week-02", "Week-03" ];

  var messageIndex = 0;

  $("#previous").on("click", function(){
   if(messageIndex > 0){
       messageIndex++;
       $("#demo").text(messages[messageIndex]);
   });

 $("#next").on("click", function(){
   if(messageIndex < (messages.length - 1)){
       messageIndex--;
       $("#demo").text(messages[messageIndex]);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Is any of it working? If not try wrapping the click event initialisers in a document.ready, i.e. `$(document).ready(function(){ <add the $('#prev... scripts in here> });` Also the code will not show on initial load. To do this just put `$("#demo").text(messages[messageIndex]);` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
//List the pages you want to include
var pageURLs = [
    "example.html",
    "example2.html",
    "example3.html",
    "example4.html"           
];

//Call the plugin
$("#page-nav").pageSequence({
    //Required
    source: pageURLs,
    //Optional
    prevText: "Previous Page",
    nextText: "Next Page",
    continuous: false
  });
 });
```

And calling bellow code in html body

```
 <body>
 <div id="page-nav"></div>
 </body>
```